# .NET Membership deletes properties not on web.config in other apps

Tags: .net, properties, web-config, profile, membership

I want to make sure that I need to label this as a risk because it is the expected behaviour. I have several applications that access one database with the credentials stored. If I connect a new application to this database and the application does not have the properties in the web.config (as shown below), the properties get deleted from the database when the user signs in.

```
<profile enabled="true">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
      <properties>         
        <add name="base_id"   type="string" />
        <add name="phone"     type="string" />
        <add name="firstname" type="string" />
        <add name="lastname"  type="string" />
      </properties>
    </profile>
```

Is there a way to avoid this and prevent properties not declared in the web.config from being deleted?